# MongoDB C# Unique field giving error with values that don't exists

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing, unique, mongodb-.net-driver

So, I've a field for my mongoDB that I declared unique, but for some reasons, if gives an error after inserting the second record, saying that the "unique" field is already used.

This is the code to create the index.

```
var tablenumber = new StringFieldDefinition<Table>("number");
var tablenumberIndexDefinition = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<Table>().Ascending(tablenumber);
Tables.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(tablenumberIndexDefinition, options);
```

This is the exception I get:

```
"A write operation resulted in an error.\r\n  E11000 duplicate key error collection: RestoVationDB.Tables index:number_1 dup key: { : null }]",
```

When I insert my first entity I have no problems but when I try inserting a second one, it gives me the exception above, any ideas ?

Comment: Read [ask] and show _all_ relevant code. The error itself is clear enough: you're trying to insert `null` for the second document. So you're not assigning the `number` property properly of the documents you're trying to insert.

Comment: Your comment about "null" made me realise something, found the problem, thanks anyways. My Model Attribute name wasn't mapped correctly, thanks :)

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that the answer that you deleted **was an answer**. I think that Kamel was wrong. If to look carefully, it can even be seen that the error tells about "null" being duplicated, so probably index references a non-existent or unused field, and it's straight way to get your answer. I'd undelete it, and add piece of your entity model to that will show that no 'number' field existed, and the question&answer will be all good.

Comment: You might also ask on meta if in doubt. On the other hand, if you choose to keep the answer deleted as not-a-proper-answer, then your question is simply unanswerable, and it'd be best to delete the question completely.